# PHP load html file when index.php loads

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display a html file from a php file. here is the code

```
<?php
public bool DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile ( string $cron.html [, int $options = 0 ] );
?>
```

Basically i want to display a remote html file without giving away the location of the html file.

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Here is an official example from the PHP documentation:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

Comment: I regard `file_get_contents` as a magic in several like cases. Don't forget +1.

Answer (score 5):

First, you messed up a little bit the formal and the actual parameters.
This is a method signature:

```
public bool DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile ( string $filename [, int $options = 0 ] )
```

This is how you call it:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("cron.html");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

In your case however, it seems unnecessary to parse the content of the HTML file as a structured content. Just dump it to the output:

```
readfile('cron.html');
```

You can also read the content of the file into a string variable:

```
$content = file_get_contents('cron.html');
```

It also works for remote files:

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
```

Source of code example: [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
<?
$location = "somelocation/file.htlml";
include($location);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use the include function ?
include(''); and/or include_once(''); Or the require -> require(''); and/or require_once('');

Hope that helped !